# Sheets formula for summing values with same name

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, formula

I am trying to sum values for individual people who have multiple rows in one column and values (prices) in another. I am trying to have a column for the summed values for each person. Right now I am using =sum for each individual person but am looking for a way to code/use a formula to streamline the process.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A,sum(B) where A is not null group by A label sum(B)''")
```